# Point particles to empty

Tags: particles, constraints

I am making a colosseum with a crowd inside. For the crowd I am using an emitter and I have a few very low poly people objects in a collection. The problem I am having, is that they are all facing towards the positive Y axis. But as you can understand, in a round colosseum I want them to be facing the middle of the arena. Any idea on how I can make sure that all the particles (so the people) face towards the middle.

Thanks in advance.[image]